# jQuery Validation Add Method Regex Number with Parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm using `jquery validate plugin` with a input field which ask to put into it a phone number and I want to add a validator method with a regex that'll valid any numbers starting with "`9 or 09 or +639 or 639 or (+63) or (+63) 9`" and 9 digit after it

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneno", function(phone_number, element) {
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 && 
        //phone_number.match(/^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/);
        phone_number.match(/^(9|09|\+639|639|\((\+63)\) 9)\d{9}$/);
      }, "<br />Please specify a valid phone number");
```

This code works and can valid any number started with `+63`, `9`, `09`, `63` except when it start with `(+63)` or `(+63) 9`
As an example, it valid `+639123456789 639123456789 9123456789` but not with Parentheses

I think that there is a mistake in the match regex

Comment: It matches `(+63) 9123456789` - you have a space in front of the 9.  https://regexr.com/44sf2  If that's not what you want, you'll need to explain how it should work better.  To add `(+63)` you need another `|`, ie: `^(9|09|\+639|639|\(\+63\) 9|\(\+63\))\d{9}$`

Comment: You should clean up a little bit the regex (for example, +639 or 639 is just \+?639, no need to do +639|639). You can use https://regex101.com/ to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^(9|09|\+?639|\(\+63\)\s?9?)\d{9}$`

This validates :

```
+639123456789
9123456789
(+63)9123456789
(+63) 9123456789
(+63)123456789
(+63) 123456789
```